# How to identify Message-ID from the Sender's mailbox

Tags: exchange, outlook-2010

We have an Exchange 2010 & Outlook 2010 environment.

When a bulk item is sent to multiple users, each of the message has the same unique message-ID. I am researching a way to identify to validate that it's the exact same item.

My problem is, there's no header information in the sent item from the sender's mailbox. The MFCMAPI for the sent item doesn't contain the PR_Internet_Message_ID field.

Does anyone know how to identify and validate that it is the same? OR any documentation that I should see these differently?

Edit:
I used MFCMAPI to review a few more messages from my sent items. Oddly, I found the PR_Internet_Message_ID on one while another message that I've sent does not contain this field. Both were composed by me, and not a part of any email chain. This have me scratching my head even more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Viewing Headers:

#### Office 2010/Exchange2010

[TechNet Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2011/03/23/hey-outlook-2010-where-are-my-message-headers.aspx). The feature is there, but by default it is buried in the interface.

#### For Newer Versions

You can do so by installing/enabling the Message Header Analyzer on Office 2013 and later from the Office Store. This works in OWA as well.

I happen to like this option as I can login to OWA on mobile and then have a really tough time parsing the info on a small screen. ;)

### Sent Items

For Sent items, the mailbox holds the copy of a message it submitted to Exchange.  The message doesn't have a `Message-ID` until it hits Exchange, and this data doesn't make it back to the Sent Item in the mailbox (not even in OWA), as you note.

### Validation

MessageID is not guaranteed to be unique globally.  If your sender is within the organization you can have more confidence that the MessageID *is* unique.  Exchange will discard duplicate MessageIDs ([old info](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2004/07/14/183132.aspx), may be out of date).

### Research

For your research, I think you should rely on Message Trace to do the tracking.  Use it first to find the message IDs, then lookup the message ID to find all recipients.

Comment: Hi Blaughw, thank you for the reply on this. I don't have any problems with locating the header, however headers are not available on sent items.